# Is the eigen matrix orthogonal and norm is 1

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Need your help.
I am given a matrix
 
$$B_4=\begin{pmatrix}2 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
-1 & 2 & -1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 2 & -1\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Eigenvectors are given by $$j{\rm th\ component\ of\ }v_k{\rm\ is\ }\sin(jk\pi/5)$$  for `I = 1 : 4, J = 1 : 4`.

I have to decide whether the vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$, and $v_4$ are orthogonal and of norm 1.

My answer

This is what I came up with when I used the formula and came up with the matrix for the eigenvectors

```
octave-3.2.4.exe:84> Q7
```

$$Q_7=\begin{pmatrix}
0.58779 &  0.95106 &  0.95106 &  0.58779\\
0.95106 &  0.58779 & -0.58779 & -0.95106\\
0.95106 & -0.58779 & -0.58779 &  0.95106\\
0.58779 & -0.95106 &  0.95106 & -0.58779\end{pmatrix}$$
`octave-3.2.4.exe:85> transpose(Q7)*Q7`

ans =
$$\begin{pmatrix}2.50000 & 0.00000 & 0.00000 & 0.00000\\
0.00000 & 2.50000 & 0.00000 & 0.00000\\
0.00000 & 0.00000 & 2.50000 & 0.00000\\
0.00000 & 0.00000 & 0.00000 & 2.50000\end{pmatrix}$$
`octave-3.2.4.exe:86> inverse(Q7)`

ans =
$$\begin{pmatrix}0.23511 & 0.38042 & 0.38042 & 0.23511\\
   0.38042 & 0.23511 & -0.23511 & -0.38042\\
   0.38042 & -0.23511 & -0.23511 & 0.38042\\
   0.23511 & -0.38042 & 0.38042 & -0.23511\end{pmatrix}$$
`octave-3.2.4.exe:87> transpose(Q7)`

ans =
$$\begin{pmatrix}0.58779 & 0.95106 & 0.95106 & 0.58779\\
   0.95106 & 0.58779 & -0.58779 & -0.95106\\
   0.95106 & -0.58779 & -0.58779 & 0.95106\\
   0.58779 & -0.95106 & 0.95106 & -0.58779\end{pmatrix}$$
`octave-3.2.4.exe:88> norm(Q7)`

ans =  1.5811

As transpose of the matrix multiplied by matrix is not $I$ and inverse is not equal to transpose I have to conclude that it is not orthogonal and norm is not 1. Please let me know if my logic and workings above are correct.

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is.

Comment: Obviously your eigenvectors do not have length 1. Of you want to find such vectors, you should multiply/divide you vectors by a suitbale constant.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $B_4$ is symmetric its eigenvectors are *guaranteed* to be orthogonal.